# Deployment Datasnap based HTML5 Builder webpage on shared hosting

Tags: deployment, datasnap, html5builder

I created webpage(webapp) in HTML5 Builder, which is running with Datasnap server. On localhost everything is OK, I can say I'm very satisfied. When I try to deploy it on low budget hosting it shows errors like:

```
Warning: require_once(rpcl/datasnap/ServerFunctionExecutor.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maniu/domains/site.com/public_html/rpcl/rpcl.inc.php on line 163

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'rpcl/datasnap/ServerFunctionExecutor.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php55/lib/php') in /home/maniu/domains/site.com/public_html/rpcl/rpcl.inc.php on line 163
```

So I  started searching and the conclusion is that this kind on webapp can't run on shared hosting. My question is: I must buy dedicated server for it? Is theres an option to deploy it on for example Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)? Or other cloud? Other ideas?

Comment: I think you probably don't have a problem. Your solution is probably here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Well I've got a Shared Hosting and the situation which descripted @Machavity . Zero contact with server administrator, so I will try do it on dedicated server

Comment: glad this helped you :)

Comment: by the way, if this helped you, can you please upvote the question and/or the answers, so that in the future, people will the same problem will find it more easily ?